# SignalR Context.User is null on OnConnected

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am working on an UI application that uses Angularjs and Asp.net web API. For real time updates I am using SignalR. Web API and SignalR are hosted in separate processes. Web API will authenticate the user and return a token. I am sending the same token in query string to the SignalR for authorization. Authorization code runs successfully but the Context.User is null within the OnConnected method, but within the Register hub method the principal is set properly.

Please find the code below. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
[TokenAuthorize]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Register(string token)
    {
      // Context.User is set to the appropiate principal
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        //Context user is set to null
    return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);

    }
}

public class TokenAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        var tokenId = request.QueryString.Get("Token");
        try
        {
            var principal = TokeService.ValidateToken(tokenId);
            if (principal != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                request.Environment["server.User"] = principal;

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }         

        return false;

    }

    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext,
        bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        var connectionId = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.ConnectionId;
        var environment = hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context.Request.Environment;
        var principal = environment["server.User"] as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (principal != null && principal.Identity != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            hubIncomingInvokerContext.Hub.Context = new HubCallerContext(new ServerRequest(environment),
                connectionId);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    protected override bool UserAuthorized(System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }

        var principal = user as ClaimsPrincipal;

        if (principal != null)
        {
            Claim authenticated = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Authentication);
            if (authenticated != null && authenticated.Value == "true")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you do not send it as message using singalr?

Answer (score 0):

It has possibly something to do with the order in which the signalr configuration auth configuration and web api configuration are called. You have to call mapsignalr before the configuration of the web api. Unfortunately, i don't know how to call the configuration of the web api before the mapsignalr function. because my web api configuration is triggered from the global.asax `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`